# OmniCppComplete vim plugin and SSD on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, vim, tags

I want to develop some GTK+ stuff in C and I was in need of using some plugin for completions. I have personal reasons why I don't want to use YouCompleteMe plugin. I configured OmniCppComplete perfectly but I have question. Does this plugin (based on ctags) affects SSD lifespan (there is one large file with tags and plugin reads each time I press tab) or I am just worried in advance? Thanks for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifespan of SSD drives is only impacted by *writes* (as this causes memory cells to be reorganized and rewritten); for subsequent reads, your tags file is probably cached by your operating system in RAM, anyway.

If you're using anything except first generation hardware, I don't think you need to worry about this. The disks have advanced wear-leveling algorithms built in, and modern operating systems detect and handle these devices very well. For typical user tasks like programming, playing games, etc., this should all work out well.